# how to run .exe file from smarterasp.net hosting?

Tags: asp.net, web

I hosted a website in smarterasp.net. now i need to run .exe files from it. Even if the file is in FTP or localdisk of the computer. Is it possible? If yes, how? If no, why?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is a bad idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to execute \*.exe in server from ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658555/need-to-execute-exe-in-server-from-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about unmanaged executable, then the answer is no.

Why? No sane shared hosting would allow you to run unmanaged executables, as there would be no security.

If we are talking about .NET executables, you can just reference it directly through references, and call the functions you need (this works because .NET offers robust security, where you can constrain everything).

It's still possible to upload executable files, but that's kind of useless, unless you want to do it for sharing purposes (enable it in control panel).