# Is it possible to write PHP in an ASP.NET page

Tags: php, asp.net, server

i have a whole website in ASP.NET and i am having problem in sending email with the C# code on the server side so i wanted to know that is it possible to write

`<?php
 ...
 ...
 ?>`

inside a **.aspx** page

Comment: @hsz this is not a dup. That question is about sharing both technologies on the same site and this one ask on the same page, witch implies a totaly diferent aproach.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658555/need-to-execute-exe-in-server-from-asp-net) may guide.  You can execute a PHP script from inside your asp.net page, as a separate application