# How can I include an external exe in my class library

Tags: c#

I've an external api rest server with the following map structure:
"[drive][folderx]\Server\". Under that folder there're some dll files, folders and an exe. At this moment I start the server by using Powershell so that I communicate with it by localhost.

I've created a class library that communicates with the server (by sending get and put commands). Now I want to host/ship the class library included with the external api rest client and also running it from in the class library.

Comment: May be this link solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679375/run-an-exe-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: Also check this too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658555/need-to-execute-exe-in-server-from-asp-net

Comment: @PramodSutar thanks I know the ProcessStartInfo way of starting a process. I want to know if there's another way and also how I can put al of this in one dll or nuget package so that the implementor can include the dll/nuget package and dan start the api rest server client